# Success handling behavior in Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: php, extjs4, ajax-request

I am working on extjs 4 project. In this project I have to communicate back and fourth between `js` and `php` files. So to call php from js, I am using Ext.Ajax.request.

```
var dirs = [];

Ext.Ajax.request(
{
    url: 'text.php',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response) 
    {
        dirs = JSON.parse(response.responseText);

    },
    failure: function(response) 
    {
        alert('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});

// Creating dropdown list menu
document.write("<select class='select'>");
for (var i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++)
{
    document.write("<option>" + dirs[i] + "</option>");
}
document.write("</select>");
```

php code is the following:

```
<?php

$filepath = "scenarios";
$dirs = array();
$files = array();

$scenes = array_diff(scandir($filepath), array('..', '.'));

for ($i = 2; $i < count($scenes)+2; $i++)
{
    if (strpos($scenes[$i], '.'))
    {
        array_push($files, $scenes[$i]);
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($dirs, $scenes[$i]);
    }
}

if (count($dirs) > 0)
{
    echo json_encode($dirs);
}
else
{
    echo json_encode("You do nat have any projects. Please create new project.");
}   

?>
```

Now the problem appears in the part where I want to generate list menu from the resulting **`dirs object`**. In the firebug DOM dirs = ["google","yahoo"], but in the loop, dirs.length returns 0???

Also when I put `alert(dirs.length)` before the for loop, it shows 0, then correctly generates the list menu...weird????

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing the question

Comment: Also, if I put the for loop inside success, the browser loops infinitely.

Comment: Can you put 2 alerts of dirs.length, one inside success and one before the loop and tell me which get executed first and the value of each?

Comment: success gets called first by showing 2, then the one before loop showing 0. Then this is what confuses me: even though dirs.length = 0 before loop, the loop gets executed and the list menu is correctly generated with 2 elements

Comment: if i don't put the alert before loop, the loop will not be executed. It seams like the alert changes/updates the state of the DOM

Comment: This is very weird :) Let's try to debug this together. First, there's a simple way to test your hypothesis. Let's move the loop back into the success and put `alert` before the loop and see what happens.

Comment: it shows 2, then only white screen with menu list (but no css is shown). And as I mention, the browser goes into loop...

Answer (score 1):

The request call is asynchronous which means, that after calling Ext.Ajax.Request, the next instruction is your loop. But you haven't received the data from the server yet. You need to put the loop in the success callback to make sure that you'll execute it after getting the data from the server.

```
var dirs = [];

Ext.Ajax.request(
{
    url: 'text.php',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response) 
    {
        dirs = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        // Creating dropdown list menu
        document.write("<select class='select'>");
        for (var i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++)
        {
          document.write("<option>" + dirs[i] + "</option>");
        }
        document.write("</select>");

    },
    failure: function(response) 
    {
        alert('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

> Also when I put alert(dirs.length) before the for loop, it shows 0,
>   then correctly generates the list menu...weird????

This is because the `alert` stop the execution flow of your program until you click on "ok". The data are probably coming from the server during this time, and the `dir` variable is populated with them.

Comment: According to OP in his comment, "Also, if I put the for loop inside success, the browser loops infinitely". That's where the "weird" comes from for me.

Comment: Putting it outside because it doesn't seem to work inside won't fix the problem.
Putting this loop inside is definitely needed.

Comment: Yes, that's what logic dictates. But the problem remains.

Comment: As I mentioned before, he *did* try what you suggested. And it threw his browser into an infinite loop.

Comment: Antoine's answer is correct, and he also provided an accurate explanation for what the OP called "weird". There's no way the code he suggests can trigger an infinite loop. Just to be solid, I *did* test it with the PHP code in the question, and it yielded the expected result. IMO the OP didn't try this exact code, and there's no more answer to be found in the code we've been given for inspection. @LimH., you've just been chasing a dragon ;p

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any headers being sent out - which is required by most browsers:

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf8;');
if(sizeof($dirs) > 0){
   echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'data' => $dirs));
}
else {
   echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'You do not have any projects.' ));
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
var xhr = new Ext.data.Connection();
xhr.request({
   url: '/text.php',
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {'Accept':'application/json'},
   success: function(response, opts) {
      var obj=Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      var html='';
      Ext.each(obj.data, function(v,i){html+='<option>'+v+'</option>';});
      html='<select>'+html+'</select>';
      console.info(html);
   }
});
```

The HTML generation has to reside in the callback function - else it makes no sense at all.

Without having seen the JSON which is being returned - it's hard to tell what's wrong with it.

Down-voting without leaving a comment **why exactly** is really lame.

Comment: This answer has been completely changed. You were saying that he is not using extjs and mixing with jquery for json_encode, which is very wrong. And your previous answer did not make any difference to the problem

Comment: Probably I was still working on it? For me this is just another one question, just like "I don't know how to use a debugger". The documentation clearly states that it is a singleton - and that "endless loop" was for sure caused because it wasn't instanced before using it. Will simply stop supporting this site, because it's nothing but a waste of time (not to mention all the bothersome recruiters).

Comment: Dear Brian, according to what you wrote, I assume you don't know Jack.
down-voting people (who actually build complex JS applications) for trying to explain the very basics to noobs - is ridiculous to me.

Comment: First, who said I down voted? Second, I know Jack, Jason, Jake, and more...take care ;)

Comment: If some mixes up PHP & JS syntax - there's no need to talk any further.

Comment: I did not vote you down, but I just voted for you. It seams that you cannot sleep at nights ;)